# Grep strings with random numeric characters

Tags: grep

I want to grep lines containing

```
 - 0 amount
 - 122,000,000 amount
 - 50,000 amount
```

I've tried to use

```
grep -rhI " - * amount ".
```

but it will output anything containing

```
 -
```

regardless of whether it contains

```
amount
```

The problem is I only want strings with

```
 - * amount
```

where `*` indicates anything in between `- (here) amount`. It is acceptable if the lines only containing " - " are dismissed.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: show the desired output

Comment: In regex, `*` isn't a wildcard but a quantifier, as `?`, `+` and `{n,m}` : it qualifies the preceding token with an amount of times it can and/or must be matched.

Comment: To precise what  @Aaron says:  in most regexp contexts :a star ( **`*`** ) means "0, 1 or n times what was just before (be it a character, or a character class, or sometimes in evolved regexp libraries, more complex things) ". a dot ( **`.`** ) means: "any character".  So **`.*`** will mean any string (as it is 0, 1 or n times any character).   thus: **`grep -rhI " - .* amount "`**

Comment: Thank you both for giving me a better understanding of the * usage & as to why it wouldn't work in this scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*` will match zero or more of the *preceding character* or pattern.

This means that `- * amount` will match

- `- amount`
- `-  amount`
- `-   amount`
- (etc.)

To match the numbers, as you have written them, use `- [0-9,]+ amount` as the pattern. The `+` will force at least one match of the preceding regular expression, and `[0-9,]` will match any digit or a comma.

Given the following file:

```
 - 0 amount
 - 122,000,000 amount
 - 50,000 amount

 - amount
 -     amount
 - some amount
```

This will work:

```
$ grep -E -e '- [0-9,]+ amount' file
 - 0 amount
 - 122,000,000 amount
 - 50,000 amount
```

The `-E` is needed because `+` is an extended regular expression operator, and the `-e` is needed because otherwise the `-` in the pattern would be interpreted as an option to `grep` (`-e` means the next thing is a regular expression for `grep` to apply to its input). Without `-E`, use `\{1,\}` in place of `+`.

You may also anchor the pattern to the start and end of the line:

```
$ grep -E '^ - [0-9,]+ amount$' file
```

This means that the `-e` is no longer needed and will ensure that the line starts with a space followed by the dash and the the number etc. as before. The string `amount` must be the last thing on the line (we anchor the word to the end of the line with `$`).

Comment: There appears to be a leading space in the file (& the pattern in the question), so `--` isn't strictly necessary here, though it obviously doesn't hurt to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work (with awk script, search for 1st token to be dash and 3th to be string "amount"):

```
awk '$1=="-" && $3=="amount" {print $2}'
```

If you want entire line to be printed use something like:

```
awk '$1=="-" && $3=="amount" {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
grep -rhI -- '- [^ ]* amount' /path/to/parent/dir/*
```

where `[^ ]*` means match any number of any characters except a space.